# raspberry pi 3 with Kodi Leia installed

Tags: wireless

I have the above configuration and successful connected it with my linksys ea8100 wireless router.
Unfortunately, my ea8100s failed me and I replaced it with linksys ea9500.
However, my pi now does not detect the SSID of my ea9500.  It also show does not show all the network names compared to my mobile phones.

Please what I should do.  Thank you.

Regards,

Ging Yang

Comment: If it's a pi3 then it can only connect to 2.4ghz networks. It will only see networks it can connect to so if your new router is setup as 5ghz only or as a combined AP (where it outputs the 2.4ghz and 5ghz channels together) then the pi either wont see it or be unable to connect. Check your routers settings and look for an option to separate the channels and once that's done you should see two APs on your phone and the 2.4ghz one on your pi and hopefully that should sort it for you.

Comment: @rohtua That's only true for RasPis not being a RPi 3B+. RPi 3B+ can use 5GHz.

Comment: What Raspberry Pi do you use? Does it is a **RPi 3B+**? What operating system do you use? Does it is **Raspbian**? Please address me with @Ingo, otherwise I won't see your reply.

Comment: @Ingo I know. That's why I said "if it's a pi 3." It hasn't been specified in the original post (unless I've missed it). I'm never sure whether people mean they're using a pi3 or a pi3b+ you see people use it interchangeably at times. :)

Comment: @rohtua Ah.. OK, have overseen that :)